# Xamarin Forms Binding Page Title from Model

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mobile

Does anyone know how to bind a Page Title from a model? I wanted to make the Name property as Title Page below is my code

Xaml

```
<ContentPage BackgroundColor="White"                           
         xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="app.MainMenuPage"
         NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False">
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

My Model

```
public class EmployeeDetails
{        
    public string PersonnelNumber { get; set; }        
    public string PrimaryContactEmail { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: that should work.  Is the BindingContext assigned?

Comment: When I hover the Binding Name I got warning/error No DataContext found for Binding Name

Comment: you did not answer the question

Comment: possible thats the reason I have no idea yet on assinging the binding context Im new to xamarin how to do it?

Comment: `this.BindingContext = new MyViewModel();`

Comment: I will try it thank you for your help jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to bind a model and display the data of our model to our page,  we need to set the model to the `BindingContext` of our page. And in general, we usually create a ViewModel for our page.

From document [ViewModel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm#viewmodel) , we know that:

> The view model implements properties and commands to which the view
> can data bind to, and notifies the view of any state changes through
> change notification events. The properties and commands that the view
> model provides define the functionality to be offered by the UI.

I created a simple demo, you can refer to the following code:

**1.create a ViewModel** (`TestViewModel.cs`) :

In this ViewModel, we can init our data(`employee` ) .

```
 public  class TestViewModel
    {

        public EmployeeDetails employee { get; set; }

        public TestViewModel() {
            employee = new EmployeeDetails { PersonnelNumber = "01", Name = "Jack", PrimaryContactEmail = "test123@gmail.com" };
        }
    }
```

**2.In OurPage.xaml.cs**

we can set the `BindingContext`

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    TestViewModel viewModel;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        viewModel = new TestViewModel();

        this.BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

**3.In `OurPage.xaml`**

we can display our data like this(`<Label Text="{Binding employee.Name}"/>`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="FormApp1214.MainPage">

    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding employee.Name}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>

    <StackLayout>

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it through your viewmodel, assigning your viewmodel to your view with the bindingContext, put this in the constructor of your view `BindingContext = new TEstViewModel();`

TEstViewModel should be the name of your viewModel.

In your viewmodel you have to have your model as a public property:

```
public EmployeeDetails Detail { get; set; }
```

Then in your XAML view you can put `Detail.Name`

```
<ContentPage BackgroundColor="White"                           
         xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="app.MainMenuPage"
          Title="{Binding Detail.Name}"
         NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False">
```